# Cursor changing buttons not being called

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am calling a function from a button in my HTML page that then sets attributes. However it does not appear to be working. I have tried changing my DOM code to see if it is the reason and I have made sure that the Cursors are the correct location. I've looked on W3 but can't find much about the documentElement.setAttribute sorry for this elementary question.

```js
function changeCursor1() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("use-my-cursor", "1");
}

function changeCursor2() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("use-my-cursor", "2");
}

function changeCursor3() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("use-my-cursor", "3");
}
```

```css
html[use-my-cursor="1"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor1.png);
}

html[use-my-cursor="2"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor2.png);
}

html[use-my-cursor="3"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor 3.png);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeCursor1()" class="buttonStyle1"><img src="Cursor1.png" class="Button1"></button>
<button onclick="changeCursor2()" class="buttonStyle2"><img src="Cursor2.png" class="Button2"></button>
<button onclick="changeCursor3()" class="buttonStyle3"><img src="Cursor 3.png" class="Button3"></button>
```

Comment: see [my modified form of your code here](https://jsfiddle.net/9yswfqqx/) (i use background instead of cursor to show that the attribute changes). Before i changed the functions to `window.changeCursor1`, it was saying that the function wasn't defined. For you to reference a function like that from an html button, the function has to be global.

Answer (score 0):

If you use default cursors, like:

```
html[use-my-cursor="1"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
html[use-my-cursor="2"] {
  cursor: help;
}
html[use-my-cursor="3"] {
  cursor: default;
}
```

as in here: https://codepen.io/davidballester/pen/pWmEXj, your code works, so your problem is probably related to the images you are using as cursors. You can refer to this page for help about how you can use custom images as cursors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Answer (score 0):

I had to add auto as in:

```
html[use-my-cursor="1"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor1.png), auto;
}
html[use-my-cursor="2"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor2.png), auto;
}
html[use-my-cursor="3"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor 3.png), auto;
}
```